# NodeJS How to send data to one specific client

Tags: angular, express, ionic-framework, websocket, notifications

I am developing a Social Network App with Ionic 4. For the Backend I use ExpressJS & Firebase. The problem is, that I don't know how to implement the real time notifications for example when a user likes the post of another one.

Socket.IO is not really an option, because I often read about the bad performance when tons of users(500k+) users are connected. I also read about [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js), but I can't find any examples that could help me implement the notifications. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you need to implement standard notifications: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be concerned about performance at 500k users at this early stage. You should be concerned about shipping and learning quickly, so if Socket.IO will help you with that (from what you describe, I'm quite sure it will), go for it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to prematurely optimize, you can cross that bridge when you get there. Swap out that piece with a service that is more scalable when you do in fact need it.